# JSON.deserializeUntyped to Map<string,Map<string,decimal>>

Tags: apex, json

I am trying to deserialize json to Map< string,Map< string,decimal>>.

**json**

```
{
"redrose": {
    "11-Jan-2019": "$1.85",
    "16-Jan-2019": "$1.85",
    "17-Jan-2019": "$1.85",
    "18-Jan-2019": "$1.85",
    "23-Jan-2019": "$1.85",
    "24-Jan-2019": "$1.85",
    "25-Jan-2019": "$1.85",
    "30-Jan-2019": "$1.85",
    "31-Jan-2019": "$1.85",
    "01-Feb-2019": "$1.85",
    "06-Feb-2019": "$1.85",
    "07-Feb-2019": "$1.85",
    "08-Feb-2019": "$1.85",
    "14-Jan-2019": "$2.25",
    "15-Jan-2019": "$1.85",
    "21-Jan-2019": "$2.25",
    "22-Jan-2019": "$1.85",
    "28-Jan-2019": "$2.25",
    "29-Jan-2019": "$1.85",
    "04-Feb-2019": "$2.25",
    "05-Feb-2019": "$1.85",
    "11-Feb-2019": "$2.25",
    "12-Feb-2019": "$2.25",
    "10-Jan-2019": "$1.85"
},
"whiterose": {
    "10-Jan-2019": "$0.61",
    "11-Jan-2019": "$0.61",
    "15-Jan-2019": "$0.61",
    "16-Jan-2019": "$0.61",
    "17-Jan-2019": "$0.61",
    "18-Jan-2019": "$0.61",
    "22-Jan-2019": "$0.61",
    "23-Jan-2019": "$0.61",
    "24-Jan-2019": "$0.61",
    "25-Jan-2019": "$0.61",
    "29-Jan-2019": "$0.61",
    "30-Jan-2019": "$0.61",
    "31-Jan-2019": "$0.61",
    "01-Feb-2019": "$0.61",
    "05-Feb-2019": "$0.61",
    "06-Feb-2019": "$0.61",
    "07-Feb-2019": "$0.61",
    "08-Feb-2019": "$0.61"
 }
}
```

I need to store this deserialize json in Map< string,Map< string,decimal>>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not replace All `$` with `''` and then parse it as `Map<String, Map<String, Decimal>> result`

```
String inputJSON = '{"redrose":{"11-Jan-2019":"$1.85"},"whiterose":{"10-Jan-2019":"$0.61"}}';

inputJSON = inputJSON.replaceAll('$','');

Map<String, Map<String, Decimal>> result = (Map<String, Map<String, Decimal>>)JSON.deserialize(inputJSON, Map<String, Map<String, Decimal>>.class);
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do the deserialisation that you want in one step because the values you want to be decimals are actually strings like "$0.61". If they were raw numbers, it would be quite simple e.g.

```
String s = '{"redrose": {"11-Jan-2019": 1.85,"16-Jan-2019": 1.85} }';

Map<String, Map<String, Decimal>> result = (Map<String, Map<String, Decimal>>)JSON.deserialize(s, Map<String, Map<String, Decimal>>.class);

System.debug(result);
```

If efficiency isn't all that important, the easiest way would be to deserialize into a `Map<String, Object>`, then traverse that Map to create the one you want. If you have to deal with large amounts of data, you could use `JSON.createParser(string)` and convert the data at the same time as doing the parsing.